# Why useDispatch not execute two action at one function?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux

I using react and redux and i want to update my state in modal component then show data which is updated in other component. The problem is i can not execute two actions at one function. Only one action can execute in this function. Anyone solution this problem? My function is below.

In component.

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();

const onFinish = () => {
  dispatch(updateMailContent(form.getFieldValue('content')));
  dispatch(setMailSubject(form.getFieldValue('contentSubject')));
  onCancel();
};
```

Action.js

```
export const updateSmsContent = content => ({
 type: UPDATE_SMS_CONTENT,
 payload: content,
});

export const updateMailContent = content => ({
 type: UPDATE_MAIL_CONTENT,
 payload: content,
});
```

In Reducer

```
case UPDATE_MAIL_CONTENT:
  return {
    ...state,
    detail: {
      mailPreview: action.payload,
      isLoading: false,
      error: null,
    },
  };
case SET_MAIL_SUBJECT:
  return {
    ...state,
    detail: {
      mailSubject: action.payload,
      isLoading: false,
      error: null,
    },
  };
```

In my state

```
export const initialState = {
 detail: {
  data: {},
  isLoading: null,
  error: null,
  smsPreview: '',
  mailPreview: '',
  mailSubject: '',
 },
};
```

Comment: There should not be any reason that two actions can't be dispatched in a method. Also you might need to add more context since this is not enough to say if somethings wrong. How are these two actions declared? Are the two slices/reducers working separately?

Comment: @FerToasted My bad sorry. I added my reducer and actions.  Where am i missing?

Answer (score 1):

**Both actions are getting dispatched, but they are overwriting each other's state changes**.  The problem is your reducer.

```
case UPDATE_MAIL_CONTENT:
  return {
    ...state,
    detail: {
      mailPreview: action.payload,
      isLoading: false,
      error: null,
    },
  };
case SET_MAIL_SUBJECT:
  return {
    ...state,
    detail: {
      mailSubject: action.payload,
      isLoading: false,
      error: null,
    },
  };
```

When you make nested updates, you need to have the `...` at every level.  In each case you are replacing the entire `state.detail` object with a new object which only has three properties.  All properties of the previous `state.detail` object will be lost.  Your `...state` will copy any other top-level properties of the `state` object, though you don't actually seem to have any other properties there.  You need to spread `...state.detail` as well.

```
case UPDATE_MAIL_CONTENT:
  return {
    ...state,
    detail: {
      ...state.detail,
      mailPreview: action.payload,
      isLoading: false,
      error: null,
    },
  };
case SET_MAIL_SUBJECT:
  return {
    ...state,
    detail: {
      ...state.detail,
      mailSubject: action.payload,
      isLoading: false,
      error: null,
    },
  };
```

Or use the official Redux Toolkit package for a much easier way to write reducers.

[Docs: Immutable Update Patterns](https://redux.js.org/usage/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns)